# Duplicate id with the same properties

Tags: jquery, css

I install popeye to slider images. When I must to create another slider show I duplicate all the css content to another id for example this

```
 #ppy1 .ppy-extcaption {
     width:          240px;
     display:        block;
}
 #ppy4 .ppy-extcaption {
     width:          240px;
      display:        block;
}
#ppy5 .ppy-extcaption {
      width:          240px;
      display:        block;
}
```

there are any form to create diferents id with same properties with less css code duplicate.

Thank you
Sorry my bad english

Comment: You can use comma, like: #ppy1 .ppy-extcaption, #ppy2 .ppy-extcaption, #ppy5 .ppy-extcaption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this:

```
[id*=ppy] .ppy-extcaption{
     width: 240px;
     display: block;
}
```

---

**Update**

> [attr^=value] Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is prefixed by "value".
>
> [attr*=value]  Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as substring.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: Thank you, with this I can put ppymanolo, ppypeter... I go to check this

Comment: if you dont mind explain a little more this example.

Comment: This is the best solution, works nice!!. [id*=ppy]  and you can put the name ppymanolo, ppy better.... Nice

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `class`

```
.ppy-extcaption {
     width:          240px;
     display:        block;
}
```

Or even you can use them like

```
#ppy1 .ppy-extcaption, #ppy4 .ppy-extcaption, #ppy5 .ppy-extcaption
{
     width:240px;
     display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I can not work with a class because the component works with a id http://dev.herr-schuessler.de/jquery/popeye/

Comment: That's why I have given both the solutions

Answer (score 3):

```
#ppy1 .ppy-extcaption,
#ppy4 .ppy-extcaption,
#ppy5 .ppy-extcaption
{
     width:240px;
     display:block;
}
```

Or if you're confident class `ppy-extcaption` isn't used anywhere else in your application, just reference the class:

```
.ppy-extcaption
{
     width:240px;
     display:block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it is not my aplication it is for 3 person.